# Securing a Personal Hotspot

Tags: wifi, monitoring, hotspot

I'm buying a brand new phone, added to it: a new line and SIM card, along with a brand new laptop, to use my phone's network as a hotspot. I will not be using these devices for anything but personal banking (I'll be visiting my broker's website and tradingview.com - absolutely no other website). I'll be using free text apps like "TextNow" to make calls and texts and will NEVER reveal my real number to anyone. As for physically securing the devices, I'm considering buying an RFID signal blocking faraday bag to  keep these devices in, and storing the bag within an aluminum storage case, painted with nickel or copper-based paint. This case will be locked.

If no one has physical access to these devices but me, run a full disk-encryption on the laptop, keep both devices consistently updated, don't store passwords in either device, avoid phishing or social engineering attempts, and constantly switch locations from where I'm accessing my hotspot, how difficult would it be for penetrating my traffic? What are some of the measures I missed to avoid wireless attacks (i.e.traffic monitoring software, browsing habits)?

Answer (score -1):

I have asked pretty much the same question for the same reasons and will follow the answers here. 
In addition to your question, I would suggest:

I am using macchanger to randomly change the MAC address on each boot. 
Using VPN on the mobile device and on the laptop. (ProtonVPN, with the Secure Connection Servers)

Using three browsers, each for different websites (one for banking, another for general browsing and another one for trading)

Restricting cookies and JavaScript, flash, images etc on browsers as much as possible. I Never store history. Deleting browsers cache on the laptop and phone daily.

My Linux is installed on a USB and its encrypted.

My phone has few apps, and I have disabled all google bloat.

I never use the same email twice.

I am still trying to figure out what mail app to use on the laptop, as I will be accessing my accounts a lot, and configuring all protocols and certificates is very important.

Comment: What attacks does random MAC protect against? VPN is a double edged sword; it requires you to trust your VPN provider - which is commonly a somewhat dodgy company in another country. What attacks does deleting history protect against? It may open you up to typosquatting attacks. What does deleting cache protect against? In short; your advise is dubious to me, and should not be generalized.

Comment: You are wrong. All of these measures greatly reduce targeting and exploiting your online activity, especially  if you are into crypto and stocks on a daily basis visiting same websites and forums which most of the times are constantly under attacks. Gathering information about you and then exploiting your system. Its all about what you appear like online, and what exploitable information you are storing on your computer. And cookies, can lead to something useful for an attacker. However, thank you for your meaningless and pointless comment. I've learned none from you.

Comment: How am I wrong? Will not deleting history open you to typosquatting attacks? Will not using VPN open you to that attack vector? How does MAC address randomization enhance privacy? It never leaves your local network... You state that I'm wrong, yet you provide no rationale for your recommendations.  And you mention exploiting your system - that requires a 0-day in your browser. If the 0-day is there, you're vulnerable. If it's not, you're not. Random MAC-address doesn't change that.

Comment: You are missing my point. I'm just saying that privacy and security go along hand by hand. If you are not taking care of OS and its apps privacy issues while using your systems you are becoming some steps more vulnerable to attacks. I didn't say these "dubious" (as you calling it) measures will stop attacks. It was just an additional advice to the OP's question.

Comment: No, privacy and security does not go hand in hand. Privacy may be a desired outcome, but it's possible to have perfect security and no privacy. Less privacy may open you to some forms of attacks but that doesn't mean that perfect privacy means perfect security. I gave two examples of this: disabling history may lead to typos in URLs. VPN's may open you up to attacks from untrustworthy VPN vendors. And some of the measures, such as random MAC address only makes sense as a privacy measure if you connect to public access points really.

Comment: It is not possible to have perfect secure system, the one you are using for all kinds of day to day activities. And lack of privacy measures will expose you and your system much more if neglected. Also if your system is compromised, and your privacy was neglected it will compromise even further to all your online activities, profiles etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106679/discussion-between-brkroot-and-vidarlo).